# TokenClassification with BERT: add tensors after text was already tokenized?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using Bert for NER TokenClassification.

Since I want to manually truncate the (training) text and add padding and special tokens on my own, the tokenizer function looks like this:

```
tokenized_text = tokenizer.encode_plus(text, add_special_tokens=False, is_split_into_words=True)
```

I have successfully trained my model and now want to use it to predict new text.
The Huggingface [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.1/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForTokenClassification) suggest to do it as follows:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**tokenized_text).logits
    predicted_token_class_ids = logits.argmax(dim = -1)
    predicted_tokens_classes = [model.config.id2label[t.item()] for t in predicted_token_class_ids[0]]
```

My problem is that in order to use the code above tokenized_text has to be in (pytorch) tensor format, but I originally did not use the `return_tensors="pt"` parameter, since I wanted to leave "input_ids", "token_type_ids" and "attention_mask" as list datatype to manipulate them easier.

So my question is basically if I can transform an already tokenized text to a tokenized text in the tensor format.

As far as the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.5.1/main_classes/tokenizer.html) tells `return_tensors="pt"` just returns `torch.Tensor` objects for the "input_ids", "token_type_ids" and the "attention_mask".

So I simply tried to use:

```
tokenized_text["input_ids"] = torch.Tensor(tokenized_text["input_ids"])
tokenized_text["token_type_ids"] = torch.Tensor(tokenized_text["token_type_ids"])
tokenized_text["attention_mask"] = torch.Tensor(tokenized_text["attention_mask"])
```

This made my tokenized text look like this:

```
{'input_ids': tensor([  101.,  5911., 26664., ....
 'token_type_ids': tensor([0., 0., 0., ....
 'attention_mask': tensor([1., 1., 1., .... }
```

Which is a bit weird, since if I use `return_tensors="pt"` from the beginning the tokenized text looks like this: (Basically it has one more layer of [ ] and not a "." after every element.

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[19770, 30882,   215, ....
 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, ....
 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, .... }
```

I tried that on a custom text just to get the reference, currently it is not really an option for me to use `return_tensors="pt"` directly during my tokenization.

If I run the prediction code as suggested by Huggingface on the `return_tensors="pt"` tokenized text it works just fine, but if I use my manually to tensor converted tokenized text I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I should change or experienced another way to predict new data with a trained model?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it after some more digging through the documentation. Turns out that just using `torch.Tensor(tokenized_text["input_ids"]` was not enough.

1. I had to add another dimension so that the tensor has the size of [1,512].
   I did this with:

   `local_copy["input_ids"] = local_copy["input_ids"][None, :]`
2. I had to typecast my tensor from float to int with:

   `local_copy["input_ids"] = local_copy["input_ids"].type(torch.int64)`